# ArrayList out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I am getting an arraylist out of bounds exception: Index 4999, Size 4999 in this method:

```
for (int y = 0; y < trees.getHeight() - 1; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < trees.getWidth() - 1; ++x) {
            int c = trees.getRGB(x, y);
            Color color = new Color(c);
            if (color.getRed() == 0 && color.getGreen() == 255 && color.getBlue() == 0) {
                treePosB.add(new Vector2f(x, y));
            }
        }
    }

    int randX = 0;
    int randZ = 0;
    boolean canPlace = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < treesAr.size() - 1; ++i) {
        randX = randInt(-terrain.getTerrainSize(), terrain.getTerrainSize());
        randZ = randInt(-terrain.getTerrainSize(), terrain.getTerrainSize());
        treesAr.get(i).setLocalTranslation(randX, terrain.getHeight(new Vector2f(randX, randZ)) - (40 + 1.0f), randZ);

        for (int x = 0; x < treePosB.size() - 1; ++i) {
       //FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES ERROR
            if (treesAr.get(i).getLocalTranslation().x == treePosB.get(x).x && treesAr.get(i).getLocalTranslation().y == treePosB.get(x).y) {
                canPlace = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (canPlace) {
            treeNode.attachChild(treesAr.get(i));
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Im not sure whats causing this, i have changed the for loops to include a ArrayList.size - 1 to adjust for this, because i knew it would happen, but it still happens. The trees ArrayLIst is created like so:

```
    treesAr = treeGen.generate(am);

    Texture tex1 = Main.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/Trees/Trees1.png");
    BufferedImage trees = ImageToAwt.convert(tex1.getImage(), false, true, 0);

    public ArrayList<Geometry> generate(int amount) {
    ArrayList trees = new ArrayList();
    Geometry tree = (Geometry) Main.assetManager.loadModel(
            "Models and Textures/Landscape/Trees/Pine.obj");
    for (int i = 0; i < amount - 1; ++i) {
        Geometry treeI = tree.clone();
        trees.add(treeI);
    }
    return trees;
}
```

What this is doing, is load an image, and check the image for green pixels and creates an arraylist with vecotrs that represent the position of each pixel.

It then loads the trees, and goes through a for loop and checks the trees randomized position. If the tree is within the pixel area, they are added to the scene, otherwise nothing happens.

This allows me to draw an image and draw out where the trees are allowed to spawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < treePosB.size() - 1; ++i) {
```

You mistyped this loop (`x` -> `i`). It increments `i` infinitely until it exceeds the size of the list.

Comment: @TastyLemons You meant to type `++x`; instead you typed `++i`.

Comment: im so stupid. Sometimes, when i copy paste from my other for loops... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TastyLemons Make sure to mark this answer as accepted (click the checkmark below the number) so that other people know that the question has been answered.

Comment: Gotta still wait 1 minute :P